# Find the Taylor series for $\sinh(x)$ and indicate why it converges to $\sinh(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Find the Taylor series for $\sinh(x)=\frac 1 2(e^x-e^{-x})$ and indicate why it converges to $\sinh(x)$.

Comment: Find Taylor series for each exponent, add them up, make sure odd terms cancel out, and you're done. It converges because residue goes to $0$ as $x$ goes to target value.

Comment: @Kaster Good enough for an answer.

Comment: The remainder goes to zero, don't know about residues.

Comment: No research or attempt was shown. Downvote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\sinh x = \frac{1}{2} ( e^{x} - e^ {-x}) = \frac{1}{2}(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-x)^n}{n!}) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(1-(-1)^n ) x^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

Comment: Yes Kernel... ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: :) ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

To show that the series does indeed converge to $\sinh x$, for all $x$, you may want to use [Taylor's Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor.27s_theorem_in_one_real_variable) The Lagrange form of the remainder will do the job.  You will need to prove, or recall, that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|x|^n}{n!}=0$.

Alternately, you can recall (if that has already been proved in your course) that the usual power series for $e^t$ converges to $e^t$ for all $t$.